# How to remove top tab Navigator while navigating to different screen in react native and reactnavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have implemented a Tab navigation just below header of the screen. It works fine But the problem is when I Navigate to different screen tab bar still remains there. I want to hide them when i go to detail screen.  I am not sure how to do that. Any Help would be great.

Here is what I want
This is my screen.
[image]

Here when I click on any of the list item i wanted to navigate to detail screen. And i do get navigated but the tab bar is still there.
Here is my code .

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const KarwarStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Karawar" component={Karwar} />
      <Stack.Screen name="KarawarDetail" component={KarawarDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const CommunityHub = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Karwar" component={KarwarStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Hubli" component={Hubli} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Bangalore" component={Bangalore} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default CommunityHub;
```

Comment: Because stack is inside tab navigator so the tabs will remain there. Please post how your navigationcontainer is setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your stack is part of the tab navigator, tabs will remain always there when you navigate to the `KarawarDetail` screen. You need to try inverse logic, a workaround could be like this

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const CommunityHub = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Karwar" component={Karwar} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Hubli" component={Hubli} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Bangalore" component={Bangalore} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const RootStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="CommunityHub" component={CommunityHub } />
      <Stack.Screen name="KarawarDetail" component={KarawarDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RootStack;
```

Comment: This fixed navigation problem but the other problem is how can I combine there props I am using react native with typescript. Do you have any idea about this. I tried looking into the docs but couldn't find right solution.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question with all your details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156569/how-to-combine-tab-and-stack-navigation-props-in-reactnavigation-typescript-reac

Comment: I did posted it 2 days ago. Please look into it